# Conversion between jboolean* and uint64_t*

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to convert a `jbooleanArray` with 128 elements (always) to a C++ array of `bool`s with 128 elements also.

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jboolean  Java_com_app_flutter_1app_JNI_loadBufferNative(
        JNIEnv *env, jbooleanArray jMidiNotes) {
    bool midiNotes[128] = {false};
    *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(midiNotes) = *env->GetBooleanArrayElements(jMidiNotes, nullptr);
    *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(midiNotes + 64) = *env->GetBooleanArrayElements(jMidiNotes + 64, nullptr);
```

I believe `GetBooleanArrayElements` returns `jboolean*`, and it looks like a `jboolean` is `uint8_t` in C++ (strange).

What am I doing wrong here? I get a crash `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x7ff426b390`.

Since `jboolean = uint8_t` I also tried

```
    *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(midiNotes + 64) = *env->GetBooleanArrayElements(jMidiNotes + 8, nullptr);
```

but I get the same crash

Comment: The jvm might do optimizations with booleans in arrays. It could store those as a bitmap or similar.

Comment: Why are you using `uint64_t` when the objects in question are (to your knowledge) `uint8_t`? Seems like a recipe for failure of one sort or another.

Comment: I don't know if the immediate problem is related to strict aliasing, but you are poised to run afoul of [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771023/c99-strict-aliasing-rules-in-c-gcc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do pointer arithmetic on object handles like that:

```
*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(midiNotes + 64) = *env->GetBooleanArrayElements(jMidiNotes + 64, nullptr);
```

You should first get a pointer to the array elements using `GetBooleanArrayElements` and then do pointer arithmetic on that pointer. For instance, do like this:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jboolean  Java_com_app_flutter_1app_JNI_loadBufferNative(
    JNIEnv *env, jbooleanArray jMidiNotes) {
    bool midiNotes[128] = {false};
    jboolean* values = env->GetBooleanArrayElements(jMidiNotes, nullptr);
    std::copy(values, values + 128, midiNotes);
```